# Делегат многоадрессный

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой не могу понять,как решить, вот, что есть:

```
 public class Info
{
    public  delegate string Method(int Value, string Name);
    public Method deleg;
    public Method deleg_1;

    public Info()
    {
        deleg = Quadratic_Equation;
        deleg_1 = Quadratic_Equation;
        deleg_1 += Cubic_Equation;
    }
    private string Quadratic_Equation(int a,string Name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 метод");
        return $"{Name} {a*a}";
    }
    private string Cubic_Equation(int a,string Name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 метод");
        return $"{Name} {Math.Pow(a,3)}";
    }
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
        Info info = new Info();
        Console.WriteLine(info.deleg(3,"Уравнение 1")); 
        Console.WriteLine(info.deleg_1(3,"Уравнение 2")); 
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Как правильно вызвать делегат `deleg_1`, если как я `Console.WriteLine(info.deleg_1(3,"Уравнение 2"));` То выводит данные только последнего метода, который прикрепил к делегату, как сделать правильно, что бы выводило данные из 1 и 2 метода, прикрепленного к делегату?(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы `Console.WriteLine` два раза отработала её надо два раза вызывать.

`deleg_1` в данном случае массив с двумя значениями. Чтобы `Console.WriteLine` два раза вызвалось надо включить его в обработку этого массива. Например, передать как аргумент:

```
public class Info
{
    public delegate void Method(int Value, string Name, Action<string> processResult);
    public Method deleg;
    public Method deleg_1;

    public Info()
    {
        deleg = Quadratic_Equation;
        deleg_1 = Quadratic_Equation;
        deleg_1 += Cubic_Equation;
    }
    private void Quadratic_Equation(int a, string Name, Action<string> processResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 метод");
        var result = $"{Name} {a * a}";
        processResult(result);
    }
    private void Cubic_Equation(int a, string Name, Action<string> processResult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 метод");
        var result = $"{Name} {Math.Pow(a, 3)}";
        processResult(result);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Info info = new Info();
        info.deleg(3, "Уравнение 1", Console.WriteLine);
        info.deleg_1(3, "Уравнение 2", Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
1 метод
Уравнение 1 9
1 метод
Уравнение 2 9
2 метод
Уравнение 2 27
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!
А вот такого рода вопрос: как правильно объявить метод, что бы можно было передавать в параметры лямбда выражение?

Comment: Всё также, только вызов можно поменять `info.deleg(3, "Уравнение 1", (v) => Console.WriteLine(v));`.